# How to update multiple columns based on multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How can i combine the following two queries into one?

First i am moving all the inspectors to different office and then also changing their office access for those inspectors which don't have any open assignment.

```
 UPDATE 
  Inspectors 
 SET 
  OfficeID = 40
 WHERE CountryID = 116 AND OfficeID = 5
```

---

```
UPDATE 
Inspectors 
SET 
OfficeAccess = ',40'
FROM Inspectors i 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * from InspectionScope insp
        INNER JOIN Assignments a ON a.AssignmentID = insp.AssignmentID
        WHERE insp.InspectorID = i.InspectorID 
        AND a.CurrentStatus = 1)
AND i.CountryID = 116 AND i.OfficeID = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Inspectors 
       SET OfficeID = 40,
       OfficeAccess = CASE WHEN a.CurrentStatus = 1 THEN OfficeAccess = ',40' ELSE OfficeAccess  END--this is a varchar field
FROM   Inspectors i 
       INNER JOIN InspectionScope insp 
           ON insp.InspectorID = i.InspectorID 
       LEFT JOIN Assignments a 
           ON a.AssignmentID = insp.AssignmentID 
WHERE  i.CountryID = 116 AND i.OfficeID = 5
```

Comment: there might be some inspectors who don't have any assignment at all

Comment: Then you should consider using a LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it is a good idea to combine them, but it should be possible.  This approach uses `left outer join` to keep all the rows in the `Inspectors` table.  This allows `OfficeId` to be set.  Then it uses a `case` statement to check for matching rows for the rest of the join (which is presumably used for filtering):

```
UPDATE Inspectors 
   SET OfficeID = 40,
       OfficeAccess = (Case when a.AssignmentId is not null then ',40' else OfficeAccess end)
FROM Inspectors i LEFT JOIN
     InspectionScope insp
     ON insp.InspectorID = i.InspectorID LEFT JOIN
     Assignments a
    ON a.AssignmentID = insp.AssignmentID AND a.CurrentStatus = 1
WHERE i.CountryID = 116 AND i.OfficeID = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

To combine both I would use left join and look for both combinations.

Something like...

```
    UPDATE Inspectors
SET OfficeID = 40
    , OfficeAccess = CASE 
        WHEN a.CurrentStatus <> 1
            OR (
                insp.InspectorID IS NULL
                OR a.assignmentid IS NULL
                )
            THEN OfficeAccess = ',40'
        ELSE NULL
        END
FROM Inspectors i
LEFT JOIN InspectionScope insp
    ON insp.InspectorID = i.InspectorID
LEFT JOIN Assignments a
    ON a.AssignmentID = insp.AssignmentID
WHERE i.CountryID = 116
    AND i.OfficeID = 5
```